# How to search Jira for all subtasks where the assignee is different than the parent issue

Tags: jira, jql, scriptrunner-for-jira

I'm using Jira cloud with ScriptRunner. I'm trying to update the filter for my scrum board so that it will show subtasks only if the assignee on the subtask is different than the assignee on the main issue.

I've gotten close using the following query, but I don't know how I can reference the parent/child issue's field instead of using `currentUser()`:

```
issueType = Sub-task AND issueFunction in subtasksOf("sprint in openSprints() AND assignee != currentUser()")
```

Instead of `currentUser()`, I need it check where the parent's assignee doesn't match the child's assignee.

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside Enhanced Search without the sprint part (Because I don't have sprints created in my test instance) and it works.

```
issueType = Sub-task AND issueFunction in subtasksOf("sprint in openSprints() AND assignee != issue.parent.assignee")
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I tried this and it returns all subtasks, regardless of whether the subtask assignee matches the parent's assignee. I think this is matching it against the literal string `"issue.parent.assignee"`. I get the same result if I change it to `issue.parent.assigneeeeee`.